# Android gps reading

Tags: android, gps

i want to create android  app that read the coordinates  according to the speed (if the app holder driving ,walking etc.)

if the app want to read the coordinates first check the speed of the holder,if he driving slowly then the app read the coordinates in each 10m and if he driving fast the app read the coordinates in each 1km.
how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the speed using [getSpeed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed%28%29)

Based on the speed you can [choose to get location fixes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) every x meters